# file_put_contents() throws 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I have used

> `file_put_contents('hello.php',"<?php print 'Hello there'; ?>");`

This, on localhost, works, but unfortunately when on live server does not work with an error of 403 forbidden. When I remove the php tags `<?php ... ?>`, I am able to save the file. Can anyone help out? Why this is happening.?

Comment: What does your live server's error log say about the 403 response?

Comment: responseText: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>403 Forbidden</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Forbidden</h1>\n<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>\n<p>Additionally, a 403 Forbidden\n error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>\n</body></html>\n"

Comment: That's not from your server's error log

Comment: The error_log has nothing

Comment: Then you're looking at the wrong thing or your live server is very badly configured. Every error should be logged somewhere

Comment: I discover PHP is interpreting the code before saving that's why it's hitting 403

Comment: I want to save the actual code in the file, in short am creating a php file using php the content should be executable when called not when saving - code can contain anything, i tried applying `header('Content-Type: text/plain;'); ` before saving still not working

Comment: None of this makes sense. A 403 response is about access permissions. Bad PHP code would produce a 500 status code. If the PHP code within your string _was_ being evaluated, your live server must have some very strange configuration since I cannot reproduce this at all with the exact code in your question. Does the 403 response come from the request to the PHP script in your question or from a separate request to `hello.php`?

Answer (score 2):

please, try

```php
file_put_contents('hello.php','<'."?php print 'Hello there'; ?>");
```

Comment: Didnt work, am using jquary $.ajax to send request, maybe the error is in ajax

Comment: Trying using form

Comment: Please explain *why* the code works, instead of just providing code. A good answer shows why the code works, the code itself, and gives detailed background information.

Comment: It was advice for the night. I stumbled with such a problem when I previously wrote xml-text. I think this is due to the interpretation of php, for which this combination of characters is significant. But I don’t know the real reason

Comment: If this were to fix the issue, you'd probably want to treat the `?>` in the same way, or just omit it entirely